# Reading nastran grid with exponent coordinate

Tags: python, floating, exponential, nastran

[Nastran GRID format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgkKC.png)

I have a problem to read the some negative exponent values from NASTRAN.bdf file.
For example, this list contains z co-ordinates.

How to convert -5.75-3 into -5.75e-3 ?

Comment: Could you embed some code snippet here of what you already tried?

Comment: @MWiesner: tried to seperate -5.75 and -3 then inserted e.  I want float value to be 8 digit wide and Right aligned.Which is not always true for below code.                                                                                      _italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `  x=  -2.3-3"`
`print x`
`if x[6]=='-':`
 ` lenx=len(x)`
`  print lenx`
 ` if lenx<7:`
`    x=x[2:6]+'E'+x[6:8]`
 `   x='{0:>8}'.format(x)`
 ` else:`
`    x=x[:5]+'E'+x[6:8]`
 `   x='{0:>8}'.format(x)`
`print x `

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak it because it did not work for negative numbers and numbers (the 8-character string) starting with spaces such as this line:

```
GRID        1234        2381.185-4.397-3  -711.5
```

So this works for me

```
def nastran_float(string):
    string = string.replace(' ','')
    x = string[0]
    y = string[1:]
    y = y.replace('-','e-')
    y = y.replace('+','e+')
    string = x+y
    s = float(string)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and wrote something like this:

```
def nastran_float(s):
    s = s.replace('-','e-')
    s = s.replace('+','e+')
    if s[0] == 'e':
        s = s[1:]
    return float(s)
```